# Exception trying to collect records from parquet file in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I don't understand why, but I can't read data from my parquet file. I made parquet file from json file and read it to data frame:

```
df.printSchema()

|-- param: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- FORM: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- URL: string (nullable = true)
```

When I try to read any record I get an error:

```
df.select("param").first()

15/07/22 13:06:15 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 4)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: problem reading type: type = group, name = param, original type = null
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addGroupType(MessageTypeParser.java:132)
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addType(MessageTypeParser.java:106)
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addGroupTypeFields(MessageTypeParser.java:96)
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.parse(MessageTypeParser.java:89)
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.parseMessageType(MessageTypeParser.java:79)
        at parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.initializeInternalReader(ParquetRecordReader.java:189)
        at parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.initialize(ParquetRecordReader.java:138)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.SqlNewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(SqlNewHadoopRDD.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.SqlNewHadoopRDD.compute(SqlNewHadoopRDD.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.SqlNewHadoopRDD.compute(SqlNewHadoopRDD.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected one of [REQUIRED, OPTIONAL, REPEATED] got utm_medium at line 29:     optional binary amp;utm_medium
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.asRepetition(MessageTypeParser.java:203)
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addType(MessageTypeParser.java:101)
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addGroupTypeFields(MessageTypeParser.java:96)
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addGroupType(MessageTypeParser.java:130)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant parquet.schema.Type.Repetition.UTM_MEDIUM
        at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
        at parquet.schema.Type$Repetition.valueOf(Type.java:70)
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.asRepetition(MessageTypeParser.java:201)
        ... 27 more
15/07/22 13:06:15 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 4, localhost): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: problem reading type: type = group, name = param, original type = null
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addGroupType(MessageTypeParser.java:132)
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addType(MessageTypeParser.java:106)
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addGroupTypeFields(MessageTypeParser.java:96)
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.parse(MessageTypeParser.java:89)
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.parseMessageType(MessageTypeParser.java:79)
        at parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.initializeInternalReader(ParquetRecordReader.java:189)
        at parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.initialize(ParquetRecordReader.java:138)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.SqlNewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(SqlNewHadoopRDD.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.SqlNewHadoopRDD.compute(SqlNewHadoopRDD.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.SqlNewHadoopRDD.compute(SqlNewHadoopRDD.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected one of [REQUIRED, OPTIONAL, REPEATED] got utm_medium at line 29:     optional binary amp;utm_medium
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.asRepetition(MessageTypeParser.java:203)
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addType(MessageTypeParser.java:101)
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addGroupTypeFields(MessageTypeParser.java:96)
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addGroupType(MessageTypeParser.java:130)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant parquet.schema.Type.Repetition.UTM_MEDIUM
        at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
        at parquet.schema.Type$Repetition.valueOf(Type.java:70)
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.asRepetition(MessageTypeParser.java:201)
        ... 27 more

15/07/22 13:06:15 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
15/07/22 13:06:15 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 8.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
15/07/22 13:06:15 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 8
15/07/22 13:06:15 INFO DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 8 (first at <ipython-input-8-5cb9a7b45630>:1) failed in 0.083 s
15/07/22 13:06:15 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 4 failed: first at <ipython-input-8-5cb9a7b45630>:1, took 0.159103 s
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-5cb9a7b45630> in <module>()
----> 1 df.select("param").first()

/home/vagrant/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.pyc in first(self)
    676         Row(age=2, name=u'Alice')
    677         """
--> 678         return self.head()
    679 
    680     @ignore_unicode_prefix

/home/vagrant/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.pyc in head(self, n)
    664         """
    665         if n is None:
--> 666             rs = self.head(1)
    667             return rs[0] if rs else None
    668         return self.take(n)

/home/vagrant/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.pyc in head(self, n)
    666             rs = self.head(1)
    667             return rs[0] if rs else None
--> 668         return self.take(n)
    669 
    670     @ignore_unicode_prefix

/home/vagrant/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.pyc in take(self, num)
    338         [Row(age=2, name=u'Alice'), Row(age=5, name=u'Bob')]
    339         """
--> 340         return self.limit(num).collect()
    341 
    342     @ignore_unicode_prefix

/home/vagrant/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.pyc in collect(self)
    312         """
    313         with SCCallSiteSync(self._sc) as css:
--> 314             port = self._sc._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jdf.javaToPython().rdd())
    315         rs = list(_load_from_socket(port, BatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer())))
    316         cls = _create_cls(self.schema)

/home/vagrant/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
    536         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    537         return_value = get_return_value(answer, self.gateway_client,
--> 538                 self.target_id, self.name)
    539 
    540         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/home/vagrant/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    298                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    299                     'An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n'.
--> 300                     format(target_id, '.', name), value)
    301             else:
    302                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 4, localhost): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: problem reading type: type = group, name = param, original type = null
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addGroupType(MessageTypeParser.java:132)
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addType(MessageTypeParser.java:106)
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addGroupTypeFields(MessageTypeParser.java:96)
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.parse(MessageTypeParser.java:89)
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.parseMessageType(MessageTypeParser.java:79)
        at parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.initializeInternalReader(ParquetRecordReader.java:189)
        at parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.initialize(ParquetRecordReader.java:138)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.SqlNewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(SqlNewHadoopRDD.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.SqlNewHadoopRDD.compute(SqlNewHadoopRDD.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.SqlNewHadoopRDD.compute(SqlNewHadoopRDD.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected one of [REQUIRED, OPTIONAL, REPEATED] got utm_medium at line 29:     optional binary amp;utm_medium
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.asRepetition(MessageTypeParser.java:203)
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addType(MessageTypeParser.java:101)
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addGroupTypeFields(MessageTypeParser.java:96)
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addGroupType(MessageTypeParser.java:130)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant parquet.schema.Type.Repetition.UTM_MEDIUM
        at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
        at parquet.schema.Type$Repetition.valueOf(Type.java:70)
        at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.asRepetition(MessageTypeParser.java:201)
        ... 27 more

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1266)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1256)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1256)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1411)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

Can someone help me with this issue? What I do wrong?

Comment: If it is important there are ~100 fields in param structure.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you renamed the columns?  I got the same error when I used a "SUM(X)" column, even after renaming.  Changing the column name before saving as a parquet file solved this for me, cf. http://trustedanalytics.github.io/atk/versions/v0.4.1/errata.html.